# Problemas com uma função chamando outra função em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou trabalhando em um sistema que, ao digitar os dados nos campos ele verifica através de uma função javascript se os dados digitados já foram cadastrados no banco. Caso verdadeiro, ele bloqueia o botão que abre a janela de cadastro, caso falso, ele deixa o botão livre para que possa abrir a janela de cadastro. 
Quando os dados são cadastrados na janela invocada, é executada a função em javascript para salvar os dados e nessa mesma função, é invocada a função de verificação, assim, quando a janela de cadastro é fechada, o sistema indica que o dado foi cadastrado e bloqueia o botão para que o usuário não cadastre novamente aquele mesmo dado. O problema é que quando invoco a "função verifica" dentro da função para salvar os dados ela não funciona.
Abaixo, segue o trecho da função que salva os dados onde invoca a função de verificação:

```
var cont = 1;
while (cont != 'E'){
    if (document.getElementById(cont+'_leitura') != null){
        pesquisarLeitura(cont, "leitura");
        cont++;
    } else {
        cont = 'E';
    }
}
$('#abreviacao').val('');
$('#comentario').val('');
CKEDITOR.instances.texto.setData('');   
document.getElementById('cadastrarLeitura2').style.display='none';
```

Comment: eu fiz um teste e troquei a variável cont em pesquisarLeituras() por '1' e funcionou, alguém pode me explicar o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?